# Python - PyODBC - multiple queries with loop

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm facing problems with sending multiple queries to SQL Server 2012 through pyODBC in Python.
I have a DataFrame with queries and I want to use it to query DB. Something like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=mySERVER;DATABASE=myDB;UID=myUID;PWD=myPSWD')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor2 = cnxn.cursor()

for i in range(len(myDataFrame.Column_w_Queries)):
    query = '"' + myDataFrame.Column_w_Queries[i] + '"'
    cursor.execute(query)
    one = cursor.fetchone()
    print(one)
```

`query` in this example is `"select * from [DB].[schema].[table1]"` (including quotes).

Problem is, that when I run `cursor.execute(query)` I got following error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'select * from [DB].[schema].[table1]'. (2812) (SQLExecDirectW)")

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the query without the surrounding quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get rid of the surrounding double quotes. For example, open up SQL Server Management Studio, and try to run:

```
"select * from [DB].[schema].[table1]"
```

You'll get the error:

```
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'select * from [DB].[schema].[table1]'.
```

Now try:

```
select * from [DB].[schema].[table1]
```

...and it should work. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would swear I was playing with quotes, but your answer help me a lot ;-)